# Printed page has different margins than speficied in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing

Paper is US Letter (8.5in x 11in / 215.9mm x 279.4mm) and I have a text box of 229.4mm x 150.9mm, in order to have 25 mm at both top and bottom margins, and 40mm to the right of left margin and 25mm to the left of right margin.

I've tried saving it first in PDF and with the rule tool I can see those distances. However, when I print (from PDF or Word) those margins are not correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Possible "fault" source:**
The printer hardware cannot print all the way out to the edge of the paper. Therefore you have hardware -imposed limits which affects the actual print. Margins "printed" into a PDF is likely "unknown" as it is copied (printed) onto paper.

**Possible remedy:**
Check the manual / datasheet / Settings of your printer and subtract these values from your document margins.